# Pointwise multiplication of two vectors obtained through matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a ready-available formula for the following pointwise multiplication, where $A, B$ are matrices and $x,y$ are vectors of coherent dimensions ?

$$Ax \odot By$$

Is it $(A \odot B) (x \odot y)$ correct?

Comment: That formula is not correct. As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad y = \pmatrix{0\\1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following formula to be helpful. If $A$ and $B$ have size $m \times n$ and $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, then we have
$$
(Ax) \odot (By) = M [(Ax) \otimes (By)]
= M (A \otimes B)(x\otimes y),
$$
where
$$
M = \sum_{i=1}^m e_i(e_i \otimes e_i)^T.
$$
Here, $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), and $I_m$ denotes the size $m$ identity matrix.